# Issue importing matplotlib in <py-script> in html code (HTML Beginner)

Tags: javascript, python, html, matplotlib, import

While trying to run a python program in my HTML script, I ran into the following error:

```
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 429, in eval_code .run(globals, locals)
 File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 300, in run coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
 File "", line 2, in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' )
```

Where line 2 is

`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`

And the full code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cellular Automata</title>
    <style>
      .footnote{
        font-family:Gill Sans;
        color:darkslategrey;
      }
      .citations{
        position:relative;
        overflow:auto;
        background-color:antiquewhite;
        border:5px antiquewhite;
        padding:40px;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  
    <title>Hello World!</title>  
    <!-- linking to PyScript assets -->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />  
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>  
    <!-- Python use code from this website: https://www.javatpoint.com/pyscript#:~:text=PyScript%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,will%20run%20in%20the%20browser. -->
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="citations">
      <p class="footnote"id = "footnote-1">[1] My footnote!</p>
      <py-script>
        #06/2023
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        print(2)
      </py-script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The script runs fine in my python editor, leading me to believe that the issue has to do with it being in an HTML file. I assume the issue may be related to where matplotlib was imported.

Comment: Please share more code from this issue.

Comment: I'm confused as to why that's necessary, as the error seems to be related to the import statement?

Comment: You only shared a single line of code but the issue may actually be related to earlier lines.

Comment: Ah. No, the first line of code is a comment.

Comment: I'm talking about your HTML script, not just your python script.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I've updated my question above -- does anything seem off?

Answer (score 0):

Following [this example](https://pyscript.net/examples/matplotlib.html), I was able to fix up your code and plot a simple plot.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cellular Automata</title>
        <style>
            .footnote{
            font-family:Gill Sans;
            color:darkslategrey;
            }
            .citations{
            position:relative;
            overflow:auto;
            background-color:antiquewhite;
            border:5px antiquewhite;
            padding:40px;
            }
        </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  
        <title>Hello World!</title>  
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css"
        />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0;">
        <p class="footnote"id = "footnote-1">[1] My footnote!</p>
        <section class="pyscript">
            <div id="mpl"></div>

                <py-config>
                    packages = ["matplotlib", "numpy"]
                    plugins = ["https://pyscript.net/latest/plugins/python/py_tutor.py"]
                </py-config>
                <script type="py">
                    #06/2023
                    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                    import numpy as np
                    x = np.arange(1,4)
                    y = np.array([5,8,9])
                    
                    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
                    ax.plot(x, y)
                    print(2)
                    display(fig, target="mpl")
                </script>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you know how I can also import numpy? I'm not sure where to find the plugin link (or if that's the right way to integrate it.)

Comment: @ConfusedDetermination You can just add numpy to the list of plugins and import normally. See my updated answer.